# Using openturns from R via reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate, openturns

I am trying to use functions from the *openturns* Python package from R. I believe it should be possible to install and import Python packages using the R-package *reticulate*, but it does not seem to work for *openturns*. Can anyone help?
It seems to work fine for other packages (such as *scipy*, *numpy* and *pandas*), but I can't get it to work with *openturns*. Installing the package seems to work fine but I get an error message when I try to import it. This is what I am doing:

```
> require(reticulate)
> 
> py_install("scipy")
+ "C:.../Local/r-miniconda/condabin/conda.bat" "install" "--yes" "--prefix" "C:/.../Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate" "-c" "conda-forge" "scipy"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.

> scipy <- import("scipy")
> 
> py_install("openturns")
+ "C:.../Local/r-miniconda/condabin/conda.bat" "install" "--yes" "--prefix" "C:.../Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate" "-c" "conda-forge" "openturns"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.

> ot = import("openturns")
Error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _common: The specified procedure could not be found.
>
```

Can anyone help? What does the error message mean and how can this be fixed?